# Reset the timer in all tabs on javascript Confirm

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In my .NET app i prompt(im using js confirm for this) the user if they want to extend their session time.
The problem here is that if user wants to extend his session time than this will only extend his session time in current tab and not resetting the sessiontimeout in other tabs.
on load of every page i call the following js

```
if (document.forms[0].ctl00$hdnSessionTimeOutWarningEnabled != null && document.forms[0].ctl00$hdnSessionTimeOutWarningEnabled.value == "true") {
    gTimerSessionTimeOut = window.setTimeout("SessionTimeOutRedirect()", 60000 * parseInt(document.forms[0].ctl00$hdnSessionTimeOut.value) + 5000);
    gTimer = window.setTimeout("Timeoutwarning()", 600 * parseInt(document.forms[0].ctl00$hdnSessionTimeOut.value - 5));

    var timerObj = document.getElementById('ctl00_theTime');
    if (timerObj != null) {
        counterTimer = window.setTimeout("countDown();", 1000);
    }
}
```

This is because the timer for other tabs is already set and extending the sessiontime here wont't reset the timer in other tabs.
The `Timeoutwarning()`function does the following

```
function Timeoutwarning() {
    var time1 = new Date();
    var result = confirm('Your session will timeout in 5 minutes. Please click OK to extend your session by ' + document.forms[0].ctl00$hdnSessionTimeOut.value + ' minutes.');
    //more logic as to what to do if confirmed or Not confirmed
}
```

if user confirms than timer will be reset.
How may i reset the timer in other tabs as well on confirm?

**please Note:** 
   `if (document.forms[0].ctl00$hdnSessionTimeOutWarningEnabled != null && document.forms[0].ctl00$hdnSessionTimeOutWarningEnabled.value == "true")`

This checks if user is in Session.While i feel logic is right in its place all i need to know is how may i reset the timer in other tabs or force the page to reload on other tabs;if that is possible. 
This JS logic goes in master page hence it will be applicable to all the pages that use this master.

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate between browser tabs using cookies. So you just need to store remaining session time in `document.cookie` and then make checks inside `Timeoutwarning()`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Rewrite the answer.

Here is a simple code that create a timer. This is only to get my idea and you should customize this code according to your requirements. Start the index.html file in two tabs and open the console on both tabs. Even the tabs started at different time, the finish time will be the same. You could extend the timer using the button "Extend Timer" on both tabs.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn-extend">Extend Timer</button>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
(function () {

    var Timer = (function () {
        var self;

        function Timer(timerName, duration, callback) {
            self = this;
            this._timerName = timerName;
            this._callback = callback;
            this._duration = getDuration(duration);
            this._timerId = window.setTimeout(onTimerDispose, this._duration);
            if (getTimerData() === null) {
                setTimerData(this._duration);

                console.log('Timer "' + self._timerName + '" started: ' + (new Date()).toTimeString());   // To be removed
            }

            window.addEventListener('storage', onStorageChangeHandler);
        }

        function getTimerData() {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(self._timerName));
        }

        function setTimerData(duration) {
            var timerData = {
                startTime: Date.now(),
                duration: duration
            };
            localStorage.setItem(self._timerName, JSON.stringify(timerData));
        }

        function getDuration(duration) {
            var resultDuration = duration,
                timerData = getTimerData();
            if (timerData !== null) {
                resultDuration = duration - ( Date.now() - timerData.startTime);
            }

            return resultDuration;
        }

        function onStorageChangeHandler(e) {
            var timerData = getTimerData();
            if (timerData !== null && self._timerName === e.key) {
                window.clearTimeout(self._timerId);
                self._duration = getDuration(timerData.duration);
                self._timerId = window.setTimeout(onTimerDispose, self._duration);
            }
        }

        function onTimerDispose() {
            window.removeEventListener('storage', onStorageChangeHandler);
            localStorage.removeItem(self._timerName);
            window.clearTimeout(self._timerId);
            self._callback({name: self._timerName});
        }

        Timer.prototype.reset = function (duration) {
            console.log('Timer "' + self._timerName + '" reset: ' + (new Date()).toTimeString()); // To be removed

            window.clearTimeout(self._timerId);
            self._duration = duration;
            self._timerId = window.setTimeout(onTimerDispose, duration);
            setTimerData(duration);
        };

        return Timer;
    }());

    function myTimerHandler(e) {
        console.log('Timer "' + e.name + '" finished: ' + (new Date()).toTimeString());   // To be removed
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('btn-extend').addEventListener('click', function () {
            timer.reset(10000);
        });
        var timer = new Timer('myTimer', 10000, myTimerHandler);
    };
}());
```

Comment: The timer is set at the time of pageload. How can i change the timervalue on window.addeventlistener?

Comment: Is that means you set new timer for each opened tab?

Comment: Yes.on load of page window.settimeout("function()",time) is called.
Soall i need to do is reset this "time" on confirm.